# #Value in IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Can anyone tell me why I am getting `#Value` error when I change the TRUE and FALSE in to words, once I have put a value into cells A7 and/or B7?

What I want to achieve: TRUE=TRUE - working, FALSE= "AWAIT" - not working. 
I have tested it in a simple if statement and it works fine! Here is the code:

```
=IF(IF(C7=1,"TRUE","FALSE"), IF(ISBLANK(D7),"DISPATCH", IF(ISBLANK(C7), "SHIPPED", "SHIPPED")))
```

Comment: Your question is no clear. please tel what are all the possible options for cells d7 and c7.

Comment: If Cell A7, B7 is Filled then E7 Will display "DISPATCH". If Cell A7, B7 and D7 is Filled then it will display "SHIPPED". Thanks

Comment: "," means "or" or  "and" ?

Answer (score 0):

on E7 enter for values both in a7 and b7:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(D7)),IF(OR(ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(B7)),"","Dispatch"),"Shipped")
```

On E7 enter for values in A7 OR B7:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(D7)),IF(AND(ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(B7)),"","Dispatch"),"Shipped")
```

Comment: That sort of works, how do you make it so when both A7 and B7 and filled it displayed 'Dispatch" in E7 not just when B7 is filled?

Comment: The formula I sent is returning  when both A7 and B7 are filled and not just one of them. do you want it to return Dispatch when only one of them is filled?

Comment: I figured it out but my code is so long and I need to make it neater, maybe this will help: `=IF(IF(IF([@[Cell Fill Status]]=1,"TRUE","FALSE"),IF(ISBLANK([@Shipper]),"DISPATCH",IF(ISBLANK([@[Cell Fill Status]]),"SHIPPED","SHIPPED")))=FALSE,"AWAIT",(IF(IF([@[Cell Fill Status]]=1,"TRUE","FALSE"),IF(ISBLANK([@Shipper]),"DISPATCH",IF(ISBLANK([@[Cell Fill Status]]),"SHIPPED","SHIPPED")))))` also I have to use this code in Column AM: `=IF(AND(ISBLANK([@Reference]),ISBLANK([@[Invoice By]])),"",IF([@Reference]<>[@[Invoice By]], 1, 1))'

Comment: Glad you got yourself sorted. When it comes to this level of complexity, Formulas can often become very clunky. Just as an idea to consider - if you use VBA and this is something you may use frequently - this may be quite a lot easier to do in a custom function, using case statements etc.